# Using append in Prolog

Tags: prolog, append

I am very new to Prolog and I am experimenting using 'append'. I am trying to write a very simple program that takes the first item of a list, and add's it to an empty list L.

Would someone please explain to me why this won't work?!

```
add_first([A|_],L) :- append(A,_,L).
```

Another quick question.

Why does this code work?

```
add_first([A|B],L) :- append(B,A,L).
```

But this code doesn't?

```
add_first([A|B],L) :- append(A,B,L).
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: None of these examples, even if append worked the way you thought, seems to reflect the verbal definition you are giving for `add_first`. Could you please give an actual example of how you want `add_first` to work successfully? The description implies you want something like, `add_first([1,2,3], L)` yields `L = [1]`. But your `append` examples all involve the tail of `[1,2,3]` which wouldn't seem relevant in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Well , `A` is the head of the list `[A|B]` and `B` is a sublist . `A` is one element so if you read the definition of append :

```
append([],L,L).
append([H|T],L2,[H|L3]) :- append(T,L2,L3).
```

you will understand that the first argument of a list is a list . So you can't give an element.

`append(A,B,L)` is wrong .